# Removing cell from GridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have two QSliders placed in GridLayout like this:

```
layout = new GridLayout();

layout->addWidget(slider_horizontal, 0, 1, 1, 2);
layout->addWidget(slider_vertical, 1, 0, 2, 1);
```

This forms a 2x2 matrix since they are both placed in a different row and column.
What i want is to remove the unused cell in the bottomright corner (position: 1,1).

The thing is that this cell is taking place in my QGraphicsView and making the area not selectable.

Later I make this:

```
sliderWidget = new QWidget(graphicsView);
sliderWidget = setLayout(layout);
```

Where graphicsView is the QGraphicsView.

My first thought was that this wasn't possible, and I had to work me around this problem.
But I want to check if this is possible with you.

I would also like to know if there is some other way to make the unused cell not taking up place in my graphics view.

Comment: Why can't you just put your `QGraphicsView` to the cell(1,1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about placing the whole Graphics View inside that bottom right cell? This sliders would be outside the graphics view but usually this shouldn't be a problem.

Not sure if you actually only want scrollbars for a view which displays a small part of a larger scene, in that case you could use these:

```
QGraphicsView::setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(...)
QGraphicsView::setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(...)
```

Comment: I actually tried to place the whole view in (1,1) right now. It works well, but does not look that good. I have scrollbars inside the view, which makes it a little bit untidy. But I will probably solve this with some sizing adjustments. Thank you!